# How to force Kubernetes to listen to specific interface

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

On my PC I have multiple network interfaces:

1. `lo 127.0.0.1` - loopback interface
2. `enp2s0  192.168.1.244` - main interface
3. `lo:40  192.168.40.1` - a virtual loopback device
4. others are irrelevant

I am running apache on both the main interface and first loopback on ports `80` and `443`
And I need that apache to be undisturbed.

So I create a virtual loopback device for kubernetes to use with IP `192.168.40.1`
But every time I am trying to attach it to kubernetes it also grabs the main interface as well.

So far here is my ingress-controller config file (important parts):

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: 192.168.40.1
  externalIPs:
    - 192.168.40.1
  ports:
    - name: web
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1380
      targetPort: web
      nodePort: 32211
    - name: websecure
      protocol: TCP
      port: 13443
      targetPort: websecure
      nodePort: 32506
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: traefik
    app.kubernetes.io/name: traefik
  clusterIP: 10.43.181.90
  clusterIPs:
    - 10.43.181.90
  type: LoadBalancer
  sessionAffinity: None
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
    - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

I tried changing both `externalIp` and `loadBalancerIP` settings but that only made kubernetes grab both `192.168.1.244` and `192.168.40.1`.

For some reason when I am trying to edit the file it shows an extra read-only section in the dashboard editor:

```
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
      - ip: 192.168.1.244
```

I guess that is whats holding the interface.

How do I prevent Kubernetes from grabbing the main interface, and make it use only `192.168.40.1`?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider? It is important to reproduce your problem. Which exactly ingress did you use? Are you really using [kubernetes ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) as you have mentioned in the tag section? What exactly is the purpose of blocking a given IP address?

Comment: It's a fresh install of k3s on my development machine, so yes bare metal.
I did not change any ingress settings other than those 2 ip's, so its using the default: traefik.
I want to block the main IP since its my development machine and I am using it to run apache and 90% of my projects run bare metal using apache.

Comment: How exactly did you create your virtual loopback device? Did you see [this page](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.0/middlewares/ipwhitelist/) about Traefik IPWhiteList?

Comment: I used this command: `ifconfig lo:40 192.168.40.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up`
It was suggested here: https://superuser.com/questions/1089092/how-to-add-a-second-local-loop-back-address
Also the solution you mentioned with traefik does not work, the interface is still bound it just returns 404 now.

Comment: I have found [similar problem](https://github.com/traefik/traefik-helm-chart/issues/342). Is it helpful for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

k3s by default binds to first public system interface.
To overwrite this behavior you need to provide `--node-ip=<listen-ip>` parameter to the server process.

Since there is no configuration (neither internal nor exteral) that allows to set that parameter, the only way of setting it is by modifying the systemd service file.

You have to modify `/etc/systemd/system/k3s.service` file and in last lines change

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/k3s \
    server \
```

to

```
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/k3s \
    server --node-ip=192.168.40.1 \
```

and restart kubernetes by running

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart k3s.service
```

This way Kubernetes will listen only on `192.168.40.1` using interface assigned to this ip.